# android paid app link to free app

Tags: android

i m developing a quiz app where, in the free version i am giving only 10 questions and lock all the other levels.When users want more questions,they should select to buy the paid version
now my questions are...
do i need to create 2 different programs?
if not, how to link both. Does linking via Intent is the only solutions?
when user downloads the paid app, the free ones get deleted or user has to manually uninstall?
Does the phone contain 2 icons of the same app?(that is rather annoying)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***do i need to create 2 different programs?***

Yes, your paid app and free app must be completely different. Even package structure of both app must be different.

***if not, how to link both. Does linking via Intent is the only solutions?***

Yes single way to link your paid app using Intent(If you are not working on web app).

example :

*Add this to the button's OnClickListener's onClick method:*

```
Intent marketLaunch = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
marketLaunch.setData(Uri.parse("market://search?q=com.android.example"));
//marketLaunch.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.android.example"));
startActivity(marketLaunch);
```

Replacing `com.android.example` with package structure of your paid app.

***when user downloads the paid app, the free ones get deleted or user has to manually uninstall?***

As Pixie said user have to manually uninstall the free app(If he want).

***Does the phone contain 2 icons of the same app?***

I don't think so, that Phone can't have two icons for same application.

Comment: There can be two icons of a single app. For example if two activities have LAUNCHER category in their intent filters then there will be an icon for each activity. But I think that Rashmi.B asks about icons for free and paid versions of the app. In this case every app will have it's own icon and these icons can be the same.

Comment: Pixie and Pankaj, thanks alot for your quick answers....Pixie, I understand implementing inapp billing is difficult. Is it possible to implement customized payment gateway where all the money comes to us instead of going to market server(Google takes part of the amount).

Comment: No, it's not. It violates the license. If you publish your app on Market then all payments must be done using Market.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [in-app billing](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html) to buy additional content from your app. Otherwise you need to create lite and full versions of your app. In this case you have to share user's progress between these apps. It can be done using [shared preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

When the paid app is downloaded, the free one is not deleted automatically. User has to delete it manually. And there'll be two icons of your app so it's better to make them different. For example you can add word Lite or Free to the free app's icon.

Comment: Thanks a ton Pixie. In one of the forums I learnt that on button click, if you put an intent to the market link of your paid app,you can get redirected to it? What happens next? Does the android market take care of billing or is it a hoax?

Comment: If an app launches Market then it just launches Market, nothing more. It's not in-app billing. If you want to implement in-app billing in your application, you should read the documentation carefully because it's not an easy task. There's a Dungeons sample in Android SDK. It's a small app with fully implemented in-app billing. You can use its code in your app with minor changes.